# Training Machine Learning Model - Neural Network - Islands Problem

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, cnn, algorithms

I was working on the following leetcode problem:

> Given a 2d grid map of '1's (land) and '0's (water), count the number
>   of islands. An island is surrounded by water and is formed by
>   connecting adjacent lands horizontally or vertically. You may assume
>   all four edges of the grid are all surrounded by water.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: 11110 11010 11000 00000
>
> Output: 1
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: 11000 11000 00100 00011
>
> Output: 3

And wrote up the following explicit solution:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class Solution:
    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        if len(grid) == 0:
            return 0

        land = ones(grid)
        parcels = len(land)
        islands = 0

        while parcels > 0:

            unexplored = []
            start = land.popitem()[0]
            parcels = parcels - 1

            print(start)

            up = (start[0] + 1, start[1])
            down = (start[0] - 1, start[1])
            left = (start[0], start[1] - 1)
            right = (start[0], start[1] + 1)

            if up in land:
                unexplored.append(up)
                del land[up]
            if down in land:
                unexplored.append(down)
                del land[down]
            if left in land:
                unexplored.append(left)
                del land[left]
            if right in land:
                unexplored.append(right)
                del land[right]

            while len(unexplored) > 0:

                start = unexplored.pop()
                parcels = parcels - 1

                up = (start[0] + 1, start[1])
                down = (start[0] - 1, start[1])
                left = (start[0], start[1] - 1)
                right = (start[0], start[1] + 1)

                if up in land:
                    unexplored.append(up)
                    del land[up]
                if down in land:
                    unexplored.append(down)
                    del land[down]
                if left in land:
                    unexplored.append(left)
                    del land[left]
                if right in land:
                    unexplored.append(right)
                    del land[right]

            islands += 1

        return islands

def ones(grid):
    ones = OrderedDict()
    height = len(grid)
    width = len(grid[0])

    for i in range(0,height):
        for j in range(0,width):
            if grid[i][j] == "1":
                ones[(i,j)] = 1

    return ones
```

But, my intuition said that finding the number of islands in a grid of ones and zeroes should be a good machine learning problem, associated with image detection.

So, I wrote the following code to generate test cases:

```
from random import randint

def make_grid():

    width = 30
    height = 30
    grid = []

    for i in range(0,height):
        row = []
        for j in range(0,width):
            if randint(0,1) == 0:
                row.append("0")
            else:
                row.append("1")
        grid.append(row)

    return grid
```

And, I then generated 60,000 cases and scored them using my explicit solution. I divided them into 50,000 train cases and 10,000 test cases.

I then tried to feed the train cases into a Keras network that was 64 nodes per layer, 10 layers deep using relu and a softmax activation function at the end. I trained the model for 250 iterations.

I got low accuracy statistics on recognizing the number of islands in the "images" on both the train and test cases.

I then tried to feed them into a Keras network using two convolutional layers, the first one 2x2 and the second one 4x4 with 64 nodes each followed by 2 dense layers with 64 nodes per layer. I trained the model for 3 iterations.

I got low accuracy statistics at predicting the number of islands in an "image" on both the train and test cases.

Is this just a bad problem for neural networks? Am I using the wrong kind of networks? Are my networks too small? Do I need to do a larger number of test cases?

Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For a start I would begin with simpler tests cases because they look rather complex (see an exemple of what you seems to simulate below). May be start with a 10x10 grid and generate 1 to 5 islands of different size.

[image]